# visual studio flutter setup

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVryH.png)

I am unable to resolve this issue

i tried to watch Youtube videos regarding this issue but they suggested to copy jbr folder to jre but it didn't work as my android studio folder doesn't have jbr folder. I am stuck with this error and I don't know what to do

Comment: Please don't post error message as image - it will be immpossible to find it again. What is more, a lot of companies blocking hosting sites and many developers can't even see what exactly you posted, so will not help.

Comment: Can you share android studio folder content what its currently showing to you and which android studio version you have ? solution is also mentioned in problem you have to update android studio as well as they used bundle jdk with android studio

Comment: The error explains that your Java Runtime is too old. Class version 61.0 corresponds to Java 17.0. Try downloading OpenJDK version 17.0 from the OpenJDK Archive since its still an older version here: https://jdk.java.net/archive/. Although if supported, you might want to download a more recent one. Then, simply unzip it somewhere on your computer and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the bin folder inside the correct JDK you just downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Please download android studio and then try to check on visual studio Because android studio is setuping this things default.